# C++ Checking if a string that is representing a date is 7 or more days before today date

Tags: c++, datetime, time, iostream, time.h

I have a date stored as a string with the format `%d.%m.%y`, for example, "08.01.2022" and I want to check if at least 7 days have past since that day in C++.
I attempted using this method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
bool dateDifference(std::string stringDate, int days){
    std::tm date; //tm
    std::time_t today = std::time(0); //today
    sscanf(stringDate,"%2d.%2m.%4y",&date.tm_mday,&date.tm_mon,&date.tm_year); //string to tm
    std::time_t date_t = std::mktime(&date) //tm to time_t
    return std::difftime(today, date_t) / (60 * 60 * 24) >= days; //return difference comparasion
} 
void WinMain(){
    if(dateDifference("05.01.2022", 7)){
        //7 or more days have past since 05.01.2022
    }
}
```

It seems to return false even if it should return true when the date is more than 7 days before today.

Comment: *It seems to return false even if it should ...*  --You should break down those statements and see which one is not behaving as you say it should.   What is the value of `std::difftime(today, date_t)`?  Once you see that returns something unexpected, then focus on that function call.  You didn't even check to see if that `scanf` actually read the values correctly.

Comment: Pass arguments to `std::difftime` the other way round. `std::difftime(end, begin)` computes `end-begin`. You pass an earlier date for `end` and a later for `begin`, so you get a negative difference.

Comment: Also, the time portion of `date` is never initialized, you have some random garbage there. `std::mktime` normalizes the values in `tm` - e.g. if the structure has 25 for the hour, `mktime` is going to adjust it to 1am on the next date. So in the end, you have garbage in `date_t`, too.

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't actually attack your problem but offers an alternative solution using `std::chrono` (which would require `C++20`, and I think MSVC compiler for `from_stream`):

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <ios>  // boolalpha
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <sstream>  // istringstream
#include <string>

int main()
{
    namespace ch = std::chrono;

    for (auto&& str : { "01.01.2022", "10.01.2022", "20.01.2022" })
    {
        std::istringstream iss{ str };
        ch::year_month_day other_day{};
        ch::from_stream(iss, "%d.%m.%Y", other_day);
        const auto today = ch::sys_days{ ch::floor<ch::days>(ch::system_clock::now()) };
        const auto delta = (today - ch::sys_days{ other_day }).count();
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << (delta > 7) << ", " << delta << "\n";
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//    true, 16
//    false, 7
//    false, -3
```

Or you could use Howard Hinnant's [date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) (C++11 onwards, header-only) together with `std::chrono`. This should work on any compiler, as demoed [here](https://godbolt.org/z/eE7ff6sja).